# I can't understand sigaction() result

Tags: linux, unix, signals, system, eof

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

void handler(int sig)
{
  pid_t pid;
  int status;

  while( (pid = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG)) > 0 )
    printf("%d\n", pid);
}

int main(void)
{
  struct sigaction act;

  pid_t pid;
  int ch;

  act.sa_handler = handler;
  sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
  act.sa_flags = 0;
  sigaction(SIGCHLD, &act, 0);

  pid = fork();
  if( pid == 0 ) {
    exit(0);
  }
  else {
    if( (ch = fgetc(stdin)) == EOF )
      printf("EOF\n");
  }
}
```

Hello, I want to know about sigaction function. If I execute this program, the result is like below.

```
[process id]
EOF
```

Why EOF is in stdin buffer after processing SIGCHLD signal ? I don't know why this happen. or Maybe I don't know how to use sigaction function ?

Comment: Oh, I add a flag option 'SA_RESTART', then it works. What is this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fgetc()` returns `EOF` if the file is at end-of-file **or** an error occurs while trying to read the character. In this case, `read()` being interrupted by a signal is an error, and the `SA_RESTART` option to `sigaction()` prevents this error.

To distinguish between EOF and error, use `feof()` or `ferror()`, or test the variable `errno`. `errno` will be `0` for the EOF case, non-zero for an error (`EINTR` in this case).